# rxjs: observable.complete is not a function

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

In the following piece of code I try to demonstrate how concatMap preserves the order of events, even if the action performed on events do not complete in order.

Now I get the error that

> delayerObservable.complete() is not a function

This basically is just taken from a tutorial. I call next(), and then I call complete(). It should work, at least that's what I thought.

I can achive the desired functionality by returning randomDelayer.first()

```
return randomDelayer.first()
```

but I would like to complete the observable from within, since I might want to send out more events than just one.

```
const myTimer = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval( () => {
    observer.next(counter++);    
    console.log('called next with counter: '+ counter);
  },2000);
});

const myRandomDelayer = myTimer.concatMap( (value) => {
    const randomDelayer = Rx.Observable.create( (delayerObservable) => {
        const delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(delayerObservable);
            delayerObservable.next('Hello, I am Number ' + value + ' and this was my delay: ' + delay);
            delayerObservable.complete(); // <<-- this does not work (not a function)
        }, delay);
    });
    return randomDelayer;
});

myRandomDelayer.subscribe( (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: What RxJS version you use?

Comment: hmm... it seems 4.1.0 (unintentionally)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are quite a few changes between version 4 and 6 of the rxjs-framework. The working version of the defective source is this:

```
const { Observable } = rxjs;
const { map, filter, concatMap, pipe } = rxjs.operators;

console.log('Starting....');

const myTimer = Observable.create((observer) => {
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval( () => {
      counter++;
      if (counter < 10){
          console.log('nexting now with counter ' + counter);
          observer.next(counter);    
      } else {
          observer.complete();
      }
  },1000);
});

const myRandomDelayer = myTimer.pipe(
    concatMap( (value) => {
        const randomDelayer = Observable.create( (delayerObservable) => {
            const delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*5000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                delayerObservable.next('Hello, I am Number ' + value + ' and this was my delay: ' + delay);
                delayerObservable.complete();
            }, delay);
        });
        return randomDelayer;
    })
);

myRandomDelayer.subscribe( (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```